# prevent default click on drag start

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am stuck with an issue
I am not able to prevent click on an element while dragging. What do i need to do in my event handlers to prevent click on dragging/ note click should work as normal while element is not being dragged

I tried prevent default and stop propagation inside the dragstart event handler, but this seems to disable the drag action and not the click action

```
this.message_list
            .addEventListener('initrow', function(o) { ref.init_message_row(o); })
            .addEventListener('dblclick', function(o) { ref.msglist_dbl_click(o); })
            .addEventListener('keypress', function(o) { ref.msglist_keypress(o); })
            .addEventListener('select', function(o) { ref.msglist_select(o); })
            .addEventListener('dragstart', function(o) {alert('33'); ref.drag_start(o);})
            .addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {alert('44'); ref.drag_start(e); })
```

alerts 33 and 44 fire on dragstart , but adding stuff like stopping event propagation or preventing default action, disables the drag and not the click.
Once again click action is needed on the same element when it is not being dragged